# the \ is being removed from my code - preg_replace('/\s+/', '', $postcode); in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, preg-replace

I'm using wordpress for my main site and I'm attempting to run some code, it should be really simple... I need to remove to strip an input to just characters with no spaces etc...

I'm attempting to use:

```
$postcode = preg_replace('/\s+/', '', $postcode);
```

however for some reason when I click save in the php plugin I'm using it becomes:

```
$postcode = preg_replace('/s+/', '', $postcode);
```

Is there any reason that a \ would be getting removed?

My site is wordpress and the plugin is Custom-CSS-JS-PHP

Comment: Not aware of such issue but you can replace `single quotes` with `double quotes`

Comment: try escaping with \, so it becomes '/\\s+/'

Answer (score 0):

Please ignore this question - I've just checked the wordpress database and the full string is in there, so clearly there is something that stops the \ displaying on the edit page.